# How to model discrete bivariate probability distributions with a 'triangular' support?

Tags: distributions, discrete-data, frequency

I'm really at a loss as to what this is called, so please tell me if this is a duplicate and I'll be happy for the question to be deleted if that is the case (though I likely will still have follow-ups to ask). If the title can be phrased more clearly, please give me suggestions as well!

Basically, we have some data that is of the form $(X_{i}, Y_{i})$ where $X_{i}$ follows a discrete probability distribution on $\mathbb{N}$, and $Y_{i} | X_i$ follows a discrete probability distribution on $\{1, 2, ..., X_i \}$. You can assume the $(X_{i}, Y_{i})$'s are iid as a simplifying assumption (in reality there's likely some autocorrelation, but I'd like to simplify for now).

Here are a couple of heatmaps with some of our data. Each heatmap is a distribution that we want to model. Darker colour means more frequent, with the x-axis being $Y$ and y-axis being $X$ (trust me that this arrangement makes sense for the data we have; I know it's confusing that the x-axis is $Y$ and the y-axis is $X$).

[image]
[image]
[image]

An important property of these things is that quite often, the modes of either $Y|X$ or $Y-X|X$ stays constant across different values of $X$.

My main question (for now) is, **what parametric distributions with a small number of interpretable parameters could be used to model this data, and what are the best ways to estimate the parameters?**  There's a gazillion variations on Poisson in my field that can be used for the marginal distribution of $X$ (people even made software to fit like 200 of those distributions to find the optimal one), but it's the $Y$ bit that's extremely challenging to me.

I would make up my own distributions, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel. If need be, I'm not against making up my own distributions and calculating their MLEs.

I would be grateful for any pointers. Once I know what distributions are available, it would be nice to know if there are ways to incorporate covariates, etc., but I want to start small!

Comment: A better approach to answering such questions is grounded on an understanding of *what the data mean.*  Often that suggests appropriate, effective models.  Distribution families determined solely by qualitative mathematical properties have no assurance of being meaningful or useful.

Comment: Look into copulas? Maybe add the tag [tag:copula]